# Using local package for Docker's requirements file

Tags: docker

I have cloned an open-source project called Flasgger (https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger) to the local folder. And added some changes to it.

Now I would like to run a Docker using a `requirments.txt`:

```
docker run \
    ...
    -r requirements.txt \
    ....
```

Before the clone the **requirements.txt** looked like:

```
flasgger==0.6.5
```

And it would download and use `flasgger` from Internet.

---

**Question:** now how would I modify the **requirements.txt** to use my local copy of `flasgger`?

Comment: This is just for local dev or prod? or both?

Comment: Probably not how python `requirements.txt.` work, but just a blind shot. If you build a version locally and tag it like `9.9.9` which does not exist in internet, then it would always look for it locally, hopefully.

Comment: @Grimmy this is just for dev purposes, no production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` in your custom flasgger source and upload the generated `.whl`-file to a private python package repository so you can install it with `pip` in your `Dockerfile` ([devpi is fairly easy to set up](http://doc.devpi.net/))

To install a python package from a private package repo:

```
RUN pip install --index-url <url for repo> <package name==version>
```

or

```
RUN pip install --index-url <url for repo> -r custom-requirements.txt
```

The advantage with a package repo is simply that you can build and tag versions of your packages with the ability to roll back or delay upgrades.

A cheaper alternative is to copy in the `.whl` file in the image and install it with `pip`.

It's also possible install a package with `pip` referencing a git repo or url. You just add the url to the requirements file.

In local development you can of course just map package directory directly into the container.

You bump into the same issue when you split a project into multiple packages were services/containers share packages. Local package repo solves this entirely. Juggling lots of `.whl` files locally quickly turns into a nightmare.